# Bootstrap 3 table border thickness, left and right margin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Boootstrap 3

Use flatly (CSS) on top of bootstrap.css

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/flatly.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Am unable to find the CSS entry that will allow me to

1. Increase the thickness of the table border from the standard 1px to 3 px
2. Reduce the margin on the left and right of the whole page
3. Make the tables wider in each row

How can I do this, please?  Have looked and looked

Thanks a bunch

Iyer

Comment: it is not a goof idea to change `bootstrap` css, i'll suggest you to write your own css and over write the BS class through it...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response.  That's what I have done.  I not at all handy with CSS but have managed by adding padding style to the TH in my table. Was wondering if that is the best way to do it. You confirm that.  Many thanks

Comment: rule of thumb : never amend core files, you never know where-all are they used in code...write custom and over write....glad i could help.. welcome!! :)